# Catch statement doesn't execute when an error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

I have the following try/catch statements but when an error occurs, the catch statement doesn't catch it.

```
try {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(sw => {
      sw.showNotification(`${this.state.selectedType.name} finished!`);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Notification error', e);
  }
```

[error statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heUAO.png)

Comment: you need to put the error handling in the `.catch` of the promise. Generally, try/catch and Promises don't work well together - that is what `.catch` is for.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Try/Catch and Promise Chains *can* work together (without issue), though it is generally recommended to use one pattern or the other and not mix the two. The issue here is the code is synchronous, so it doesn't `await` the promise to resolve or reject, so when a rejection does occur the code execution has likely already returned from this function.

Comment: using try/catch with promises is usually in conjunction with async/await - when using `.then` to catch errors you would use `.catch`

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(sw => {
      sw.showNotification(`${this.state.selectedType.name} finished!`);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

You cannot use try{} and catch {} like that when using axios since axios has it's own way of catching expections
You need to use try{} and catch{} in an async method if you want to do it another way, but this way should work now with .then().catch()

Comment: I am getting the following error statement: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'showNotification' on 'ServiceWorkerRegistration': No notification permission has been granted for this origin.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `try/catch` with `.then()` in this case but you can use them with `async/await`.

Your code using `.then()`

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
  .then((sw) => {
    sw.showNotification(`${this.state.selectedType.name} finished!`);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('Notification error', err);
```

And the same code using async wait (assuming this code is in an `async` function):

```
try {
  const sw = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');

  sw.showNotification(`${this.state.selectedType.name} finished!`);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Notification error', e);
}
```